# Using Selenium to get list of javascript called from a web page

Tags: javascript, selenium

Using Selenium is it possible to get a list of javascript calls a web page executes?
For example this web page: https://ideal-postcodes.co.uk/address-finder?

I wish to see what url the web page makes javascript calls to and from that url what javascript it also executes. So I have a stacktrace of javascript calls.
[image]

[image]

Only thing I'm able to find is the html page source.